# How do I get fullscreen div without iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

My website https://saxobroko.gq has multple divs as different windows and when I take away the divs they stop fitting the whole page.

I've tried using css to make it fullpage without the iframe and with just `<p>Test</p>`

I want the iframe to fit the users view without having an iframe in it.

**Edit:**  I will include the before and after code.

**Before (Not Working):**

```
<style>
.sec1 {background-attachment: fixed;min-height: 100%;background-position: center;background-repeat: repeat-xy;}
</style>
<div class="sec1">
     <iframe src="#"></iframe>
</div>
```

**After (Working):**

```
<style>
.sec1 {background-attachment: fixed;min-height: 100%;background-position: center;background-repeat: repeat-xy;width:100%;height: 101vh;}
</style>
<div class="sec1">
     <h1>Sec1 Test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be good if you provide the source code with the image pointing the issue. That helps to look into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try applying this style into your `ifram`s that are wraped in the `div` with  `sec(*) w3-center` class name.

for example :

```
.sec4 w3-center > iframe {
   width: 100%
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: but i dont want the iframe to be there.

Comment: I'm just a little confused. without iframe how do you show your content? 
if you wanna show them directly in a `div` you just have to add above style to your root `div` to show your content with `fullHeight` and `fullWidth` in the screen.